# Net Core 2 equivalent of ChildActionOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What is equivalent of ChildActionOnly in MVC Net Core 2? I am migrating .Net 4.6.2 project to Net Core 2.

```
    /// <returns></returns>
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `ChildActionOnly` equivalent in `ASP.NET Core`. Use [view components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2) instead. Also see [different](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/01/02/goodbye-child-actions-hello-view-components.aspx) [blogs](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/294/view-components-in-asp-net-core-mvc) related to this.